# how to conditionally select dataframe rows by comparing column values with a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have the following list and dataframe in Python:

```
import pandas as pd

my_list = ["a", "b", "d"]

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2': ["a", "b", "c", "d"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2
0   1       a
1   2       b
2   3       c
3   4       d
```

But I only want to have such rows in the dataframe where values of **col2** also exist in **my_list**.

The final output is supposed to look like the following:

```
    col1    col2
0   1       a
1   2       b
2   4       d
```

How can I achieve this **without using a for loop**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use df.apply for this

```
df[df['col2'].apply(lambda x: x in my_list)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.query(f"col2 in {my_list}")
```